# Как обрабатывать серверные ошибки в react? (AXIOS & react-query(tanstack))

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requests, frontend, axios

Есть ситуация, пользователь регистрируется - отправляет запрос на бэк. Пользователю на почту приходит верификационный код, который нужно ввести на сайте чтобы продолжить регистрацию. И проблема в том, что если пользователь запрашивает код еще раз, выбрасывается ошибка

> Unhandled Runtime Error AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400

В тоже время от бэка в response.data.message приходит

> "An account with email useremail@email.com already exists."

Я использую react query и у меня создана функция onError чтобы отлавливать ошибки и в идеальном случае так обрабатывать:

```
onError(error) {
  console.log('регистрация ошибка', error);
  if(error.data.message.indexOf(already exists)){
    return <div>код уже отправлен</div>}
},
```

Но проблема в том, что AXIOS ловит ошибку раньше и я не нашел как в AXIOS проигнорировать ошибку и передать её в react-query.

index.ts

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
})
```

authService.ts

```
import api from '../api/index';

export const register = async (registrationData: IAuthRegisterRequest) => {
  const response = await api.post<IAuthRegisterResponse> (AUTH_REGISTER, registrationData)
  return response
}
```

authorization.mutation.ts

```
import { register } from '@/services/authService';
const authorizationConfig = {
  registerConfig: {
    key: 'register',
    request: async (params: IAuthRegisterRequest) => {
      const res = await register(params);
      return res.data;
    },
  },
};

export const useRegistrationMutation = () => {
  const { registerConfig: config } = authorizationConfig;
  const state = useMutation(config.request, {
    useErrorBoundary: true,
    onSuccess(data) {
      console.log('регистрация начата', data);
    },
    onError(error) {
      console.log('регистрация ошибка', error);
    },
  });
  return state;
};
```

RegistrationForm.tsx

```
  const { mutateAsync: mutateSignUp, isLoading: isLoadingRegister, isError, error } =
    useRegistrationMutation();

    if(isError){
     return <div>error: {error?.toString()}</div>
    }
```

Вопрос: Как обойти и передать ошибку из AXIOS в react-query? Или может есть какие-то другие подходы?
[image: консольная ошибка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как мне отвечали ранее(но стерли), обходить AXIOS не нужно.
Нашел две свои ошибки.

1. npm run dev - помогает разработчикам и показывает ошибки в "своих" окнах. (npm run build + npm run start это решает)
2. в authorization.mutation.ts я переопределяю стандартное поведение `onError`, поэтому `isError` и `error` в RegistrationForm.tsx пустые и не идут дальше. Удалил функцию onError все заработало.

Comment: Я стер вопрос из-за того что оно вам не помогло.

Comment: @Randall все равно спасибо за помощь, я начал думать в правильном направлении